# Что происходит при передаче статического массива в качестве параметра?

Tags: c++

```
void func(int arr[10]){...}
int main(){
int A[10]={...};
func(A);
return 0;
}
```

Будут ли скопированы элементы массива arr в функцию при вызове данного кода, и если да, можно ли как-то исправить это с помощью указателей?

Comment: В C/C++ передача массива по значению не поддерживается, тут и так передается указатель и статических массивов в приведенном коде нет. А вообще передавайте array_view

Comment: А проверить? :) Сделать массив, дать какие-то значения, в функции изменить и посмотреть? Откуда такая беспомощность? https://ideone.com/Jidm3D — посмотрите...

Comment: @harry то, что нам кажется простым и очевидным, другим людям может быть суперсложным и наоборот.

Comment: *`"Будут ли скопированы элементы массива arr в функцию"`* -- нет. Будет передан адрес первого элемента массива